# Dynamically creating React components using recursion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, recursion

I'm trying to create react components dynamically based on my JSON structure using a recursive function. Here is my implementation.

[image: Edit Dynamic Components from JSON with React (forked)]

components.js

```
import React from "react";
import Text from "./components/Text";
import Image from "./components/Image";

    const Components = {
      text: Text,
      image: Image
    };
    
    export default (block) => {
      if (typeof Components[block.type] !== "undefined") {
        return React.createElement(Components[block.type], {
          key: block.id,
          block: block
        });
      }
      return React.createElement(
        () => <div>The component {block.type} has not been created yet.</div>,
        { key: block.id }
      );
    };
```

dummy data

```
const data = {
  userId: 123123,
  pages: [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: "div",
      data: { text: "hello" },
      content: [
        {
          id: 123,
          type: "text",
          data: { text: "hello" }
        },
        {
          id: 456,
          type: "image",
          data: { source: "url", link: "url" }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a third argument in the [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) which is to render the children. Extended your `Components` component like below to do the recursive rendering:

```
const ComponentsMap = {
  div: Div,
  text: Text,
  image: Image
};

const Components = (block) => {
  if (typeof ComponentsMap[block.type] !== "undefined") {
    return React.createElement(
      ComponentsMap[block.type],
      {
        key: block.id,
        block: block
      },
      block.content ? block.content.map((subComp) => Components(subComp)) : null
    );
  }
  return React.createElement(
    () => <div>The component {block.type} has not been created yet.</div>,
    { key: block.id }
  );
};

export default Components;
```

Working Demo:

[image: Edit Dynamic Components from JSON with React (forked)]

Comment: thank you, I managed to sort it in a different way, but I will accept this answer